# Is there way to sort questions on "unanswered/my tags" page by date?

Tags: feature-request, tags, sorting, tabs

Is there way to sort questions on "unanswered/my tags" page by date? There is a "newest" tab, but it's shows all questions, not only with my tags.

Comment: +1 -- I think this should be the default behavior...

Comment: @rogerdpack, I agree. "My tags" is stuff I'm interested in, the highest-voted of those I've probably seen a dozen times already. If I'm looking in there, it's because I want to see if there is anything _new_.

Answer (score 10):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=activeperl+or+activestateperl+or+perl&sort=newest

If you want every tag that has Perl in it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=~perl~&sort=newest

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks I'd vote this up if I could.

Comment: I have about 30 tags so this method is not very convenient.

Comment: Unless you change your "interested tags" all the time, it's trivial to just bookmark your gigantic URL.

Comment: @GeoffreyZheng, that is definitely much more cumbersome than just going to the "My Tags" link.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually craft the URL and then bookmark it.

`https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tagnames=**tag1** **tag2** **tag3**&tab=newest

Comment: I just wanted to try this but stuck on tag146.

Comment: This seems to be an AND between *tag1*, *tag2* and *tag3*.  Is there a way to do this with an OR like the `my tags` tab?

Comment: On closer inspection it also appears that the `tab=newest` parameter does not actually cause it to sort by the newest.

Comment: Yes, this is an 'AND' search.  To make it an 'OR' search simply put 'or' betwee the tags: 'tag1 or tag2 or tag3'.  I do believe the results are in chronological order.  Perhaps the "modified date" is throwing you off?  Open the questions and look at the date they were asked.

Comment: The default search order is which-ever search order you used last. To force a search order you use `&sort=newest`.

Comment: @BradGilbert, that doesn't work.

Comment: @vonbrand it may have changed since I wrote that comment. (It's also possible it was wrong at the time) The thing is that any post or comment on Meta may become wrong at any moment. I wouldn't trust any that are more than a year old.

Answer (score 0):

Someone 'just' posted a question about standardizing all the page's tabs to feature tabs like newest on every page. Considering it covers a the same (and a little more) ground than this request, you might want to go upvote it.

[Inconsistent buttons on different pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10665/inconsistent-buttons-on-different-pages)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've started playing with this through trial and error and I've made some progress:

**Examples**

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23+asp.net?tab=newest

This still has the AND problem but its a start.