# Inconsistent buttons on different pages

Tags: feature-request, questions, search, user-interface

The ordering buttons are completely inconsistent. These are the ordering buttons I've found, and where I found them (please add any I've missed):

- Questions: newest, featured, hot, votes, active.
- Answers:   oldest, newest, votes.
- Unanswered Questions: my tags, newest, votes.
- Questions (in profile): votes, newest, views, recent.
- Favourites (in profile): votes, newest, views, recent.
- Votes (in profile): no options at all.

Problems:

- I can search for Newest, but not Oldest (except in answers), Hottest but not Coldest, most votes but not least votes (**and searching for least active questions is important**),
- Each page has a different set of buttons,
- On the recent page, I can see "week" and "month", but I can't do this on the question page
- Can't search for combinations:

  - Hottest this month,
  - Coldest today,
  - Least votes of all time.

Comment: That last paragraph sounded weird.

Comment: Which bit? I don't see it.

Answer (score 7):

Also, there's a difference between a *filter* and an *order*.  To take Unanswered as an example, "My Tags" means "filter out anything that doesn't have one of my tags."  "Newest" means, "order the questions by date."  It would be nice to be able to combine these - I would very much like, for example, to be able to show "Unanswered questions with my tags, ordered by date."

Comment: This is exactly what i was trying to do when I found this question..

Answer (score 6):

I suggest we have an Up and Down Button next to the tabs, so you can search is Ascending or Descending Order (accordingly).

I don't think that all pages need to have all tabs however, because if every page has every tab things start to get cluttered.

Comment: That's certainly the most important.