# Add another subtab on the "Questions" page

Tags: feature-request, my-tags

Right now, we have "newest", "featured", "hot", "votes" and "active" as subtabs on the "Questions" page at Stackoverflow - what I'm missing is a sub tab called "My tags".

**Motivation:** I would like to be able not just to filter out questions with tags that don't interest me (negative - blacklist), but I'd like to have a way to say "show me only questions that are of interest to me" that have at least one tag that I'm interested in (positive - whitelist).

Any takers?

Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have this on the unanswered tab. So I think it would be very fitting to have it on the other tabs aswell.

Someone asked this same question here: [Inconsistent buttons on different pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10665/inconsistent-buttons-on-different-pages/11279#11279)

Comment: YES !! My thoughts exactly - I have more than just two or three tags of interest - combining those as suggested by Jeff is at best a workaround for a little while.....

Answer (score 0):

You should be browsing by tag, if you want to be that narrow.

Try combining tags.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Jeff - works fine, but I'm interesting in a lot more than just two or three tags, and combining all those together in the query string seems unnecessarily complicated and tedious. And you already have this feature on the "Unanswered questions" page - why not also add it to the basic "Questions" page??