# Unanswered is not updated?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there way to sort questions on “unanswered/my tags” page by date?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/is-there-way-to-sort-questions-on-unanswered-my-tags-page-by-date)

Ran into something I hadn't expected:

If I look at the Questions tab ("Newest Questions") I see several highlighted questions (which I assume means that they  include a tag I have said I'm interested in).  These questions have zero answers, and are near the top of the list.

When I click on the "Unanswered" tab I expect to see those same "highlighted" questions, at the top, since it makes sense to me that both lists be ordered by "latest activity" since more recent questions typically are still lacking but have tractable answers.

The "highlighted" questions *are* there, but it turns out they're buried in what appears to be a random order "somewhere among the 50 pages total."

This makes it hard to use--I'd have to browse through all 50 pages to discover any "new" unanswered questions.

So a feature request proposal: sort the questions listed on the Unanswered page by most recent, as well, to make it more intuitive.

Comment: I suppose another option would be to add another "tab option" of "my tags newest" (currently there are "my tags" "newest" and "votes")...

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you are missing the `my tags` tab at the right column.
[alt text http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/1950/mytags.png](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/1950/mytags.png)

Comment: That's actually the one I was referring to--and suggesting that it default to being ordered by latest update...

Comment: @rog: Oh, then it is a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/is-there-way-to-sort-questions-on-unanswered-my-tags-page-by-date