# How to order new questions with my tags in reverse chronological order

Tags: support, tags, unanswered-questions, sorting, question-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there way to sort questions on “unanswered/my tags” page by date?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/is-there-way-to-sort-questions-on-unanswered-my-tags-page-by-date)

When I select 'unanswered' questions and the 'my tags' tab I would like to see the newest questions with any of my tags, ignoring relevance.

Is this possible and if so how would I do this?

Comment: Duplicate: [Is there way to sort questions on “unanswered/my tags” page by date?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8559/147650)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find a [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)  script that does this - there are [loads of SO GreaseMonkey scripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/greasemonkey-script-ideas-best-of-stackoverflow-greasemonkey-implementations) already out there.

Comment: Your second link points to a deleted question.  The new home is http://stackapps.com/?tab=apps.  However, postulating that there might be a script doesn't solve the problem.